# How to use if in stubs in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, stub

I have an artisan command which gets some options, one of these options is `--type=`, like below:

```php
protected $signature = 'make:procedure {name} {--type=}';
```

`--type=` contains the kind of difference, I want to check this option in the stub because each type has a different namespace which should be used in the stub.

for example, this is my stub:

```
<?php

namespace DummyNamespace;

class DummyClass
{
    //
}
```

How can I do this, (of course this is an example, I just trying to explain my problem):

```
<?php

namespace DummyNamespace;

if ($type === 'one') {
echo 'use App\Some\Namespace\One'
}

class DummyClass
{
    //
}
```

It would be highly appreciated if anyone can advise me!

Comment: I think I should use different stubs! But is there no other way?

Comment: You could use `php artisan stub:publish` to publish Laravel's stubs and check them. In none of those stub an `if` exists. Looks like you need to make that decision in your command and use different stubs

Comment: stubs are read in, then particular strings are replaced in them then they are written to a file ... so you can make your stub have some string in it that you can look for to replace with your "aliases" as a string you are building based on your conditionals

Comment: you can explain to me how to do this or how to pass the "aliases" into stub? @lagbox

Comment: does your artisan command extend `GeneratorCommand` ?

Comment: yes, I extend `GeneratorCommand` @lagbox

Answer (score 0):

your Custom command should derive from GeneratorCommand then you can use abstract Method getStub()
Your Stub File

```
namespace DummyNamespace;

/**
 * Class DummyClass.
 */
class DummyClass
{
    
}
```

In Your Command File, you just need to use below code

```
   /**
     * Get the stub file for the generator.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getStub()
    {
        return app_path('file/path/test.stub');
    }
```

For Explanation Only 
In **GeneratorCommand** class

```
     /**
     * Get the stub file for the generator.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    abstract protected function getStub();


    /**
     * Build the class with the given name.
     *
     * @param  string  $name
     * @return string
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException
     */
    protected function buildClass($name)
    {
        $stub = $this->files->get($this->getStub());

        return $this->replaceNamespace($stub, $name)->replaceClass($stub, $name);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to generate files from stub.

In your stub file

```
namespace {{namespace}};

/**
 * Class {{name}}.
 */
class {{name}}
{
    
}
```

Somewhere in your command

```
protected function getStub()
{
    return file_get_contents(resource_path('stubs/dummy.stub'));
}
```

```
protected function generate($namespace, $name)
{
    $template = str_replace(
        ['{{namespace}}', '{{name}}'],
        [$namespace, $name],
        $this->getStub()
    );

    file_put_contents(app_path("Dummies/$name.php"), $template);
}
```